# Issues with javascript using html inputs as variables (Beginner!)

Tags: javascript

**Hello Everyone!**

Im having some issues with a simple calculator type website. My issue involves using a javascript function to calculate an equation using variables from an HTML input form.

Below is my javascript function, which is placed above the form in the HTML file.

```js
              var userName = document.getElementsByName("userName")[0].value;
              var userMmr = document.getElementsByName("userMmr")[0].value;
              var userDesmmr = document.getElementsByName("userDesmmr")[0].value;
              var userWinrate = document.getElementsByName("userWinrate")[0].value;

              function findshit(){
                alert(userMmr.value);

                var LR = 1.0 - userWinrate.value;
                var GP = 1;

                while (1){
                  var GW = GP * userWinrate.value; 
                  var GL = GP * LR;
                  var MMRG = GW * 25;
                  var MMRL = GL * 25;
                  var TMG = MMRG - MMRL;
                  if (TMG + userMmr.value >= userDesmmr.value) {
                    alert("Congrats! it will take you " + String(GP));
                  } else {
                    GP += 1;
                  }
                }
              }
```

```html
<h2>Enter your information below</h2>
          </br>
         <form>
            What's your name?:<br>
            <input type="text" name="userName" onkeyup="findshit();" onchange="findshit();"/><br>
            </br>
            What's your current mmr?:<br>
            <input type="text" name="userMmr" onkeyup="findshit();" onchange="findshit();"/><br>
            </br>
            What's your desired mmr?:<br>
            <input type="text" name="userDesmmr" onkeyup="findshit();" onchange="findshit();"/><br>
            </br>
            What's your current win rate?<br>(put in decimal form eg. 50% = .50):<br>
            <input type="text" name="userWinrate" onkeyup="findshit();" onchange="findshit();"/"><br>
            <br>

          
            <button onclick="findshit();">Try it</button>
```

Comment: And the exact problem you're having is? What debugging have you done? What errors do you get in the browser's console? What do you think `while (1)` will do?

Comment: You need to get the values of the inputs inside the function. You're just setting them once when the page first loads, not after the user changes the values.

Comment: `userMmr.value` makes no sense. You used `.value` when you set `userMmr` in the first place.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? And what exactly are you trying to do? You haven't even asked a question...

Comment: If the answers solved your problem and you have a new problem, you should ask a new question (and optionally accept an answer.) Modifying your question such that it invalidates existing answers is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `.value` when you set all the variables at the top. The code in the function expects those variables to just be the elements, because it uses `.value` to get their updated values. So it should just be:

```
      var userName = document.getElementsByName("userName")[0];
      var userMmr = document.getElementsByName("userMmr")[0];
      var userDesmmr = document.getElementsByName("userDesmmr")[0];
      var userWinrate = document.getElementsByName("userWinrate")[0];
```

You also need to put the script **after** the HTML, or put all the code inside the `window.onload` function. If you run the script before the HTML is loaded, none of the `document.getElementsByName()` calls will find the elements.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove or modify while (1) loop. Because it is an infinite loop. I think you should use If loop in the scenario.